# GDM3 is programed to start on VT1. Is there a way to change it

Tags: systemd, gdm

I would like to start GDM3 in VT9 (because it is running in a container. I do not want to have a conflict). Is there a way of doing that.

1. Modifying and adding to `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` `FirstVT=9` did not help.
2. changing and adding to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`   `NAutoVTs=9` did not help.

Is there any other way of doing it without recompiling gdm3?

Answer (score 1):

it looks as usual they have f*cked it so that the only way to change it 
is to set the environment variable `XDG_VTNR`.

For example, `Environment=XDG_VTNR=9` in `gdm.service`

Or `-e XDG_VTNR=9` on your `docker` command.

On a regular desktop this is apparently set by `pam-systemd`, presumably based on some other configuration.

Comment: does not work on gdm 3.34